# Re-parse the content of a box register

Tags: boxes

I'll ask the question first and then explain why it is so. I have the following .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\newsavebox{\myquote}
\setbox\myquote=\hbox{\begin{normalsize}\verb.'.\end{normalsize}}

\usepackage{upquote} % convert verbatim ' from left single quote to a "normal" single quote

\begin{document}
Test: \verb.'. vs \usebox{\myquote}
\end{document}
```

In this tex file, the `\verb.'.` turns out as a `'`, and the `\usebox{\myquote}` looks like a curly left single quote. This is because even though I `\usepackage{upquote}` (which converts the curly left single quote to the straight single quote within verbatim/verb), it's loaded in *after* the definition of `\myquote` so it's too late for the `upquote` package to affect what sort of quote happens in `\myquote`.

**Question: assuming I can *only* put code *after* the `\setbox` line, is there some way to make the quote mark in `\myquote` appear as a straight single quote?**

I am basically looking to add a command like `\edef\myquote\myquote` after the `\usepackage{upquote}`, so that the definition of `\myquote` is basically re-evaluated before assigning it back to `\myquote`. The re-evaluation will cause the `\verb.'.` to be parsed according to the modifications made in `\usepackage{upquote}`, causing the quote to be a single quote again.

You may ask why I don't use load `upquote` before I define `myquote`; well, I am using a document generation package called Sweave (for the language R). I basically can embed write R code into my (otherwise LaTeX-looking) document, call Sweave on it, and it will produce a .tex file with the code (& results) nicely printed within. Sweave inserts all of these `\newsavebox` commands *before* the preamble that I put in the original document. That is, **I cannot change the order of the `\newsavebox` command to be after the `\usepackage{upquote}`**.

As a last resort I can copy/paste the `\setbox\myquote=\hbox...` that gets generated by Sweave into my own document preamble (i.e. after the `\usepackage{upquote}`), but then should the Sweave package change their definition of `\myquote` (say they change the `normalsize` to something else) I'll have to change my definition to remain in sync.

It'd be preferable to do the re-definition as if I **only** knew the command was `\myquote` (and knowing it has `\verb.'.` in it somewhere so that I know the `upquote` package will have effect) and not its actual definition.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. AFAIK box content is typeset when the box is assigned. The actual code like `\begin{normalsize}\verb.'.\end{normalsize}` (which BTW should be `\normalsize\verb.'.`) is not present and available any longer. The box register already contains the lower level typesetting material, which AFAIK can't be really changed any longer.

Comment: Ok, so I'll just stick to looking at the generated `\setbox` line & copying it to my preamble after I load in `\upquote` for now (I know the definitions are not as elegant as they could be, but I have no control over them - they are generated). cheers!

Comment: @MartinScharrer That's correct: please post it as an answer.

Comment: @JosephWright: Done

Comment: In addition to Martin's answer it is best to avoid _any_ typesetting in to boxes before `begin[document}` laTeX makes a paragraph break be an error in that context to discourages but allows single line setbox/savebox settings for legacy compatibility. However many aspects of the font setup are not initialised until begin[document} even if you don't load any packages. (in case you do load packages)

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcommand{\myquote}{\texttt{\textquotesingle}}` (requires the `textcomp` package) help?

Comment: No, because the sweave package defines `\myquote` as a box & uses it as such when it generates the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible. AFAIK box content is typeset when the box is assigned. The actual code like `\begin{normalsize}\verb.'.\end{normalsize}` (which BTW should be `\normalsize\verb.'.`) is not present and available any longer. The box register already contains the lower level typesetting material, which AFAIK can't be really changed any longer.

The best solution is to get the definition of the box again and reassign it after loading the formatting packages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to looking for the definition of the box and re-assigning, and just have to take my chances with the definition changing in future versions.