# Is it possible to remove (or otherwise nullify) a whatsit node from a box?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, whatsit

I am aware that it is not generally possible to modify the contents of a box (as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49903/17427), though I believe it is sometimes possible to "unbox" material and hack away at it (but not familiar with that).

However, my interest at the moment lies in **removing (or disabling) a `\write` node from a box**, which would not affect how it appears etc. The motivation for this is primarily as per [my "answer" here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81675/17427) regarding the way `beamer` puts a shrunk copy of slides in the notes pages and the resulting multiply defined labels it causes. For the purposes of the MWE, suppose I am creating a box that contains a `\label`, but I want to show that box twice, once with the `\label` taking effect and later without, and I want to prevent the multiple labels issue without subverting other features of the labelling mechanism in general, and without collecting the raw code in the box and processing it twice.

I'm sure this is possible with LuaTeX, and I'm interested in solutions both with and without LuaTeX (hence I haven't tagged this as {luatex}).

MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingonline2
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen

\newbox\boxa
\newbox\boxb

\newcommand{\showtwo}[2]{\showtokens{^^J^^J#1, #2^^J^^J}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

{
\setbox\boxa\hbox{abc\label{hi}def}
\showbox\boxa
\setbox\boxb=\copy\boxa
\box\boxa

\let\write\showtwo
% edit \boxb somehow
\showbox\boxb
\box\boxb

}

\end{document}
```

The approach I've tried to take at the moment is not to delete the node from the box (as I have no idea where to start), but rather to add an extra layer of indirection to the `\write` before it goes in the box via `\latelua`, and then I should theoretically be able to change the behaviour of the indirection layer without editing the box. This may not be a good idea in general (thoughts?), but it shows I've made some effort! However, according to the manual, "the result of using `tex.print` from inside callbacks is undefined", and I am not sure if `\latelua` is considered a callback. In any case, the only things I've managed to do from a `\latelua` without my commands being silently ignored are `tex.error` and `tex.sprint([[\noexpand\undefinedcs]])`, and certainly nothing like `tex.sprint([[\unexpanded{\immediate\write\@auxout{...}}]])`.

Lua indirection attempt (but note my label isn't written to the `aux` file before I disable writing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingonline2
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen

\newbox\boxa
\newbox\boxb

\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{\maxdimen}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\label}{\protected@write}{\protected@labelwrite}{}{\showtokens{patching \label failed}}
\let\protected@labelwrite\protected@write
\patchcmd{\protected@labelwrite}{\write#1}{\latelabelwritehelper{#1}}{}{\showtokens{patching \protected@labelwrite failed}}

\newcommand*{\latelabelwritehelper}[2]{%
    \latelua{tex.sprint([[\noexpand\latelabelwrite{#1}{#2}]])}}
\newcommand*{\latelabelwrite}[2]{\immediate\write#1{#2}}
\newcommand*{\disablelatelabelwrite}{\let\latelabelwrite\@gobbletwo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

\setbox\boxa\hbox{abc\label{hi}def}
\showbox\boxa
\setbox\boxb=\copy\boxa
\box\boxa

\disablelatelabelwrite
\showbox\boxb
\box\boxb

\end{document}
```

(Note also that this is my first real attempt to do something in Lua!)

Comment: One other idea would be for my `\latelua` node to replace itself with a real `\write` node? But again, I'm stuck as to how one might go about that.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the write whatsit, outputting the box with `\leaders` ignores write whatsits.

Comment: Well for instance, my TeXPower package, which also outputs boxes multiple times, uses `\global\setbox\@cclv=\hbox{\leaders\copy\@cclv\hskip\wd\@cclv}` to "filter out" whatsits before shipout.

Comment: So, `\setbox\boxb=\hbox{\leaders\copy\boxa\hskip\wd\boxa}` would be a possible solution.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Thanks very much. I have used this suggestion in a patch to `beamer` in the linked question. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it (though other answers regarding Lua will still be of interest!)

Comment: Btw, another thing to be very careful about when copying boxes is to get the color stack out of whack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the write whatsit, outputting the box with `\leaders` ignores write whatsits.

So, `\setbox\boxb=\hbox{\leaders\copy\boxa\hskip\wd\boxa}` would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can not, in classic TeX, remove a whatsit node, however if you have control over the macro layer and can control the construction of the original box you can arrange that the whatsit never appears in the top level list and is always protected by a box that you can remove.
This is one of the main reasons why LaTeX3 xgalley code needs to take full control of all vertical commands, so that it can adjust vertical lists afterwards.

In this case you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingonline2
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen

\let\oldlabel\label
\def\label#1{\hbox{\oldlabel{#1}}}
\newbox\boxa
\newbox\boxb

\newcommand{\showtwo}[2]{\showtokens{^^J^^J#1, #2^^J^^J}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

{
\setbox\boxa\hbox{abc\label{hi}}
\showbox\boxa
\setbox\boxb=\copy\boxa
\box\boxa

\let\write\showtwo
% edit \boxb somehow
\setbox\boxb\hbox{\unhbox\boxb\setbox0\lastbox}
\showbox\boxb
\box\boxb

}

\end{document}
```

Producing

```
> \box26=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\kern0.27779
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\write1{\newlabel{hi}{{1}{\thepage }}}

! OK.
l.17 \showbox\boxa

? 
> \box27=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x15.27782
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\kern0.27779
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c

! OK.
l.24 \showbox\boxb
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for my (old) MWE, but what if I don't know that the `\label` or `\write` is the last item in the box? Your unbox/rebox trick doesn't appear to work in that situation.

Comment: You loop through the box copying nodes that want copying and not ones that don't want copying. This latter can be interesting as you have to recognise the box. You could for example reject all zero sized boxes but that might be too agressive or you could make your guard box have a recognisable size say depth -1sp and reject all such boxes or...

Comment: well actually it's a bit harder in hmode as in your example as there are more non-removable item types notably characters that you would have to hide.

Comment: Thanks, so you're suggesting that a pure TeX solution is probably too difficult. What do you think of Stephan's idea in the comments about using `\leaders`? I have got it working as a patch for `beamer` but not sure if you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Using `\leaders` is a brilliant suggestion for suppressing `\write` I told him in chat to make it an answer so he picks up some rep point votes:-) When I said "a bit harder" in the comment above it was English understatement it could be roughly translated into "you would have to redesign the whole of latex" so not impossible but...

Comment: Thanks, I have used the `\leaders` solution in the `beamer` patch in the previously linked question (and now just need to bring it to the attention of the `beamer` maintainers).