# Re-use a saved box without label and hyperlink issues

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Background: For each class I usually have a TeX file containing both stuff for me and stuff I distribute to the students.

Sometimes I give out only a short text or a couple of exercises, so to save paper I save the content in a box, print the same box three or four times on a page, and then I cut the printed page. However, as soon as the environment contains some counters and labels I'll get warnings.

A minimal code showing the issue is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand*{\printmethreetimes}[1]{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{#1}%
   \copy0 \copy0 \copy0
}

\begin{document}
\printmethreetimes{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{baz}\arabic{foo}) something something dark side}
\clearpage
As we see in \ref{baz}
\end{document}
```

which clearly complains with `` LaTeX Warning: Label `baz' multiply defined `` and `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{foo.1}) has been already used`.

My current workaround is therefore to print the box once, then deactivate `hyperref` and `\label`, save the box again and print it twice more, thereby using the `\savecounters@` and `\restoreconters@` macros from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\newcounter{foo}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\printmethreetimes}[1]{%
   \savecounters@
   \vbox{#1}%
   \restorecounters@
   \setbox0=\vbox{\let\label\@gobble\begin{NoHyper}#1\end{NoHyper}}%
   \copy0 \copy0
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\printmethreetimes{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{baz}\arabic{foo}) something something dark side}
\clearpage
As we see in \ref{baz}
\end{document}
```

This seems to work, until I have a numbered equation in it, which reminds me that I need also to add `\let\label@in@display\@gobble`... and someday something else will break.

Maybe I'm missing the forest for the trees, but is there another way to print a saved box without all these problems? Some `\protected@copy` would be nice `:-)`

Comment: Maybe a different approach: the `pgfmorepages` package has layouts to repeat the same page multiple times

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the pointer, I gave a quick look to the doc, it might be a valid alternative.

Comment: you could use one of the externalize packages and reinsert with \includegraphics.

Comment: if you are printing on paper, do you need hyperref at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The part printed on paper is the bit I give to the students but maybe two or three pages later in the document I might refer to some equation in the repeated box. I don't need `hyperref` tomorrow, but when next year I'll look into it and ask myself "can I use the same stuff of last year?" it won't be a printed sheet I'll be lloking into but the pdf.

Comment: is luatex an option?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82250/2388

Comment: the \leaders suggestion from Stephan seems to work fine with your example.