Can \write behavior be suppressed, or can it be removed from list?
I'm using \write with \pdfsavepos to get offsets for text inside a box.  I'm setting the box, then shipping it out more than once.  My question:  is there any way to suppress the write behavior after the first shipout, without having to recreate the box?
MWE:
\setbox1=\hbox{ABC\pdfsavepos\write-1{\the\pdflastxpos}}
\shipout\copy1 % shows 6450708 in log (will vary based on font)
\shipout\copy1 % shows same info, which I don't need again
...

I'm wondering if there's a trick for...

removing \write or other whatsit from a box, e.g., something like \last...
redefining \write after it's added to a box, or
otherwise suppressing the writing to a file or log.

NEW INFO: apparently this is something of a duplicate question.  See Is it possible to remove (or otherwise nullify) a whatsit node from a box?.  The solution using \leaders was given in this post. Also, I found the suppression of \write (and other whatsit items) inside of leaders to be documented in a few places, including TeXbyTopic.  It's not "black magic" as I wrote in a comment below.

\setbox3=\hbox{\leaders\copy1\hskip\wd1} and then \copy3 instead of \copy1 in the follow up uses.

In this special case, probably: \setbox1=\hbox{ABC\hbox to 0pt{\pdfsavepos\write-1{\the\pdflastxpos}}}\shipout\copy1 \setbox1=\hbox{\unhcopy1\setbox1=\lastbox}\shipout\copy1

That's an interesting use of \leaders.  I didn't realize no writes occur within it.  Is that documented somewhere, or was it discovered by some TeX-miner digging around?

I slightly prefer the solution by @ulrich-diez because of the logic.  It's a more explicit removal than suppression (where the suppression relies on a little dark magic ;-).  But either solution works for me.  I'll wait to see if anyone else suggests something, then I'll flip a coin and mark an answer.

@DanLevin In TeXbook, Chapter 21: Making boxes, you find two double dangerous bend paragraphs right before exercise 21.10. The first of them says:
"TeX ignores \write, \openout, and \closeout whatsits that appear within boxes governed by leaders. If you are upset about this, you shouldn’t be."

@DanLevin Also see section 1374 of Donald E. Knuth's tex.pdf. (The content of less recent releases of tex.pdf is also available as Donald E. Knuth's Computers & Typesetting, Volume B - TeX: The program)

@UlrichDiez An answr?

I lead toward leaders as the best way to suppress a write, because it's so intentional, according to the man himself (Knuth).  @Ulrike-Fischer do you want to write this up as answer so you get credit for it?

I got the idea from Stephan's answer to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82250/2388

OK.  I don't know how to specify an answer in this situation.

Another trick is redefine the written contents:
% arara: pdftex
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\def\ThePdfLastXPos{\the\pdflastxpos}

\setbox1=\hbox{ABC\pdfsavepos\write-1{\ThePdfLastXPos}}
\showbox1 % shows the box contents for debugging
\shipout\copy1 % shows 6450708 in log (will vary based on font)

\def\ThePdfLastXPos{}
\shipout\copy1 % shows an empty line

\csname @@end\endcsname\end

The \showbox... lines are for debugging, the contents of box 1 is shown in the .log file:
> \box1=
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x21.8056
.\tenrm A
.\tenrm B
.\tenrm C
.\pdfsavepos
.\write-{\ThePdfLastXPos }


! OK.
l.7 \showbox1

The \write node contains the token \ThePdfLastXPos that is redefined after the first \shipout command to be empty.

thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that early on and didn't find it satisfactory because of the blank line in the log file.  So it was hunting for a solution that truly suppressed the write.
