# write the content of an hbox in an auxilary file

Tags: luatex, boxes

I know that TeX can't write the content of hbox in an auxiliary file ([Re-parse the content of a box register](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49897/re-parse-the-content-of-a-box-register)).

That mean that

```
\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname.txt
\setbox0=\hbox{bar}
\immediate\write\foo{\box0}
```

can't write
However, can LuaTeX do it? I have found

```
\directlua{
 n = tex.getbox(0)
}
```

But I don't understand what `n` is  representing and if I could use it to write the box content in a file.

Comment: If you indent your code by four spaces or click the `{}` button with more than one line selected, the code will display correctly.

Comment: sorry, too accustomed to the github syntaxis.

Comment: What are you hoping to get out here? If you show the content of a box using classical TeX you'll see that it's a series of typesetting instructions not anything necessarily related to 'text'. I wonder what the aim is here.

Comment: eledmac number line. To do it, it split vboxs to little vbox (one by \baselineskip) and then add the line number. I would like to output one specific line to auxiliary file.

Comment: A likely better approach is to catch the macros/text *before* they are consumed in a box.

Comment: No, I need precisely to get it as there are split in the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:
here is a new code that works for ligatures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{Příliš žluťoučký \textit{kůň} úpěl \hbox{ďábelské} ódy, diffierence, difference}
\directlua{
    % local fontstyles = require "l4fontstyles"
  local char = unicode.utf8.char
  local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
  local glue_id  = node.id("glue")
  local hlist_id = node.id("hlist")
  local vlist_id = node.id("vlist")
  local disc_id  = node.id("disc")
  local minglue  = tex.sp("0.2em")
  local usedcharacters = {}
  local identifiers = fonts.hashes.identifiers
  local function get_unicode(xchar,font_id)
    local current = {}
    local uchar = identifiers[font_id].characters[xchar].tounicode
    for i= 1, string.len(uchar), 4 do
      local cchar = string.sub(uchar, i, i + 3)
      print(xchar,uchar,cchar, font_id, i)
      table.insert(current,char(tonumber(cchar,16)))
    end
    return current
  end
  local function nodeText(n)
    local t =  {}
    for x in node.traverse(n) do
      % glyph node
      if x.id == glyph_id then
        % local currentchar = fonts.hashes.identifiers[x.font].characters[x.char].tounicode
        local chars = get_unicode(x.char,x.font)
        for _, current_char in ipairs(chars) do
          table.insert(t,current_char)
        end
      % glue node
      elseif x.id == glue_id and  node.getglue(x) > minglue then
        table.insert(t," ")
      % discretionaries
      elseif x.id == disc_id then
        table.insert(t, nodeText(x.replace))
      % recursivelly process hlist and vlist nodes
      elseif x.id == hlist_id or x.id == vlist_id then
        table.insert(t,nodeText(x.head))
      end
    end
    return table.concat(t)
  end
  local n = tex.getbox(0)
  print(nodeText(n.head))
  local f = io.open("hello.txt","w")
  f:write(nodeText(n.head))
  f:close()
}

\box0
\end{document}
```

Result in `hello.txt`:

```
Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy, diffierence, difference
```

---

**Original answer**:

Variable`n` in your example is a node list. Various types of nodes exists, such as `glyphs` for characters, `glue` for spacing, or `hlist` which is the type you get for your `\hbox`. `hlist` contains child nodes, which are accessible in `n.head` attribute. You can then loop this child list for glyphs and glues.

Each node type is distinguishable by value of `n.id` attribute. Particular node types and possible attributes are described in chapter "8 Nodes". In this particular example, we need to process just `glyph` and `glue` nodes, but you should keep in mind that node lists are recursive and various nodes can contain child lists, like `hlist`, `vlist`, etc. You can support them with recursive call of `nodeText` on current node `head` attribute.

Regarding glyph nodes, `char` attribute contains unicode value only in the case if you use opentype or truetype fonts, if you use old 8-bit fonts, it contains just 8-bit value which actual encoding depends on used font encoding and it isn't easy to convert it to unicode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{Příliš žluťoučký \textit{kůň} úpěl \hbox{ďábelské} ódy}
\directlua{
    local fontstyles = require "l4fontstyles"
  local char = unicode.utf8.char
  local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
  local glue_id  = node.id("glue")
  local hlist_id = node.id("hlist")
  local vlist_id = node.id("vlist")
  local minglue = tex.sp("0.2em")
  local usedcharacters = {}
  local identifiers = fonts.hashes.identifiers
  local function get_unicode(xchar,font_id)
     return char(tonumber(identifiers[font_id].characters[xchar].tounicode,16))
  end
  local function nodeText(n)
    local t =  {}
    for x in node.traverse(n) do
      % glyph node
      if x.id == glyph_id then
        % local currentchar = fonts.hashes.identifiers[x.font].characters[x.char].tounicode
        table.insert(t,get_unicode(x.char,x.font))
                local y = fontstyles.get_fontinfo(x.font)
                print(x.char,y.name,y.weight,y.style) 
      % glue node
      elseif x.id == glue_id and  node.getglue(x) > minglue then

        table.insert(t," ")
            elseif x.id == hlist_id or x.id == vlist_id then
                table.insert(t,nodeText(x.head))
      end
    end
    return table.concat(t)
  end
  local n = tex.getbox(0)
  print(nodeText(n.head))
  local f = io.open("hello.txt","w")
  f:write(nodeText(n.head))
  f:close()
}

\box0
\end{document}
```

`nodeText` function returns text contained in the node list. It is used to print `\hbox` contents to the terminal and to write to file `hello.txt` in this example.

For basic info about font style, you can try to use [l4fontstyles](https://github.com/michal-h21/lua4ht/blob/math/l4fontstyles.lua) module, like this:

```
local fontstyles = require "l4fontstyles"
...
if x.id == glyph_id then                                                        
        table.insert(t,char(x.char))
        local y = fontstyles.get_fontinfo(x.font)
        print(y.name,y.weight,y.style)
```

Comment: thank a lot for the answer and explanation ! it's what I need !

Comment: just another question. In LuaTeX handbook, I don't find anything about the possible value of note.id. I unerstand 37 = non blank charater, 10 = blank charater, but what else is possible? is it possible to get some information about formating, like weight or emphase?

Comment: @Maïeul see updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand that the id. value was the number in parenthesis in the begining of chapter 8.

Comment: it seems some problem with combineed unicode charecter. In input `ךְ` ( U+05DA U+05B0) becomes in output (but not .pdf) ``, (U+DB80 U+DC07). Does there any library to solve this problem?

Comment: @Maïeul it is written to the fille `hello.txt` as U+05DA U+05B0. LuaLaTeX see the combined characters as two characters and it doesn't seem that it does any conversions

Comment: @indeed. So it must be any other personal code which is problematic.

Comment: ok, it seems that `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}` create the problem but not `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[]{Ezra SIL}`

Comment: @Maïeul so it is probably remapped in the font. I don't know how to solve that, maybe using open type feature file?

Comment: something mapped in one sens could be mapped again in the other sens. Of course. But, for my specific problematic, it doesnt matter. The .pdf has no importance, and so I could forget the arg.

Comment: Will this code work for all cases? Or is it just a partially functioning proof of concept? Thanks

Comment: @reportaman honestly, I don't know. it is five years old and there were lot of changes in LuaTeX since then, so I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: Like I wonder if there is a way to determine hyphen added by Tex instead of it being really part of the word. What makes that complex is that some words with real hyphen I guess can be hyphenated.

Comment: It depends on when you call this function. When you call it before line breaking, you should be fine. Otherwise, hyphen should be the last glyph in hlist with character equal to `tex.hyphenchar`, I think.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks, I just tried to compile, and it fails on `local fontstyles = require "l4fontstyles"` with error `lualibs-basic-merged.lua:378: attempt to call a nil value (fie
ld 'cpath specification')`

Comment: Also, this code skips the characters of ligatures, probably because they are 'disc' nodes. For instance an english word like difference gets reported as dierence, as if ff never existed.

Comment: And this: Try adding the word `diffierence` (instead of `difference`), a word with `ffi` ligature breaks the compile completely. Error message: `bad argument #1 to 'char' (invalid value)`, while the word `difference` with `ff` ligature doesn't break compile (just doesn't print `ff` in the output). Otherwise works fine! The recursion through nested boxes works seamlessly :)

Comment: @reportaman `l4fontstyles` seems to be used only for debugging message, so you can remove it. and also remove `local y = fontstyles.get_fontinfo(x.font)`.

Comment: @reportaman it seems that for ligatures it return several Unicode codepoints in one string, but we convert the whole string to number. this results in invalid value.

Comment: @reportaman I've updated my answer with a new code that works for ligatures

Comment: I used another approach to get similar result, for which I will post a related question, and link this to it. Though instead of get_unicode function, I just iterate through the complex composed glyphs, and discs to get the character.

Comment: @reportaman the main purpose of `get_unicode` is to correctly convert glyph.char nodes back to Unicode. glyph.char contains a glyph index after Harfbuzz shaping, so it is necessary to convert it back to Unicode.

Comment: @micah Can’t you iterate through ligature/shaped glyph  nodes to get its Unicode components? The decomposed glyph data is stored under the glyph node afaik. That’s how I am able to get the components of shaped glyphs back.

Comment: @reportaman it loops over ligature glyph components, see ` elseif x.id == disc_id then`. But you still have to process glyphs that have no Unicode representation, like some ligatures or process of shaping of Arabic and other complex scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted my code (that seems to produce same result without get_unicode function), and asked a question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563731/luatex-utf-8-character-extraction-is-one-way-more-accurate-and-or-preferable-t

Comment: Both of our techniques fail when using HarfBuzz renderer, I have posted complete code with error signature here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563794/devanagari-utf-8-text-extraction-fails-in-harfbuzz-mode-passes-in-node-mode