# Renderer=HarfBuzz, Renderer=Harfbuzz throw Unkown option error for lualatex, lualatex-dev texlive 2020

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luahbtex, lualatex-dev

For the code in question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563731/luatex-utf-8-character-extraction-is-one-way-more-accurate-and-or-preferable-t), I get error `` ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `Renderer=HarfBuzz' for package `fontspec-luatex' `` when I pass option `Renderer=HarfBuzz` or `Renderer=Harfbuzz` to package `fontspec` for both `lualatex` and `lualatex-dev`. Below is the complete log:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=lualatex 2020.9.11)  22 SEP 2020 10:42
 restricted system commands enabled.
**temp3.tex
(./temp3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-08-31 2.72 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-08-31 2.72 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / parsers
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/main/Library/texlive/20
20/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-08-31.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2020-08-31.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e353f7ced917p+1
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/main/Library/texlive/20
20/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-define 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / HarfBu
zz font loading
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-plug 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / HarfBuzz
 shaping
Inserting `Harf pre_output_filter callback' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'
.
Inserting `Harf wrapup_run callback' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `Harf finish_pdffile callback' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `Harf glyph_info callback' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / letter
spacing
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / embolden
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / notdef
Lua module: luaotfload-suppress 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / suppress
Lua module: luaotfload-szss 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / Special featu
re handling
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-09-02 3.15 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/main/Library/texli
ve/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count164
\c@section=\count165
\c@subsection=\count166
\c@subsubsection=\count167
\c@paragraph=\count168
\c@subparagraph=\count169
\c@figure=\count170
\c@table=\count171
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count172
\Gm@cntv=\count173
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count174
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen135
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen136
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen137
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen138
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen139
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen140
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen141
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen142
\Gm@dimlist=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-09-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2020-09-01 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count176
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count177
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count178
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count179
))
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/21 2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count187
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count188
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count189
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count190
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen143
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen144
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen145


! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `Renderer=HarfBuzz' for package `fontspec-luatex'
.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.452 \ProcessOptions*
                    
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2019/11/18 v2.7d Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
\MT@toks=\toks17
\MT@count=\count191
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 790.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen146
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1354.
\MT@listname@count=\count192

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def
File: microtype-luatex.def 2019/11/18 v2.7d Definitions specific to luatex (RS)
Module microtype Info: overwriting function `keepligature' on input line 59
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 695.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 695.
\MT@outer@space=\skip49
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2019/11/18 v2.7d microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/09/01 3.48 The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/09/01 3.48 Babel common definitions

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\l@dumylang=\language2
Package babel Info: Non-standard hyphenation setup on input line 117.
\l@nohyphenation=\language3
\l@german-x-2019-04-04=\language4
\l@ngerman-x-2019-04-04=\language5
\l@afrikaans=\language6
\l@ancientgreek=\language7
\l@ibycus=\language8
\l@arabic=\language9
\l@armenian=\language10
\l@basque=\language11
\l@belarusian=\language12
\l@bulgarian=\language13
\l@catalan=\language14
\l@pinyin=\language15
\l@churchslavonic=\language16
\l@coptic=\language17
\l@croatian=\language18
\l@czech=\language19
\l@danish=\language20
\l@dutch=\language21
\l@ukenglish=\language22
\l@usenglishmax=\language23
\l@esperanto=\language24
\l@estonian=\language25
\l@ethiopic=\language26
\l@farsi=\language27
\l@finnish=\language28
\l@french=\language29
\l@friulan=\language30
\l@galician=\language31
\l@georgian=\language32
\l@german=\language33
\l@ngerman=\language34
\l@swissgerman=\language35
\l@greek=\language36
\l@monogreek=\language37
\l@hungarian=\language38
\l@icelandic=\language39
\l@assamese=\language40
\l@bengali=\language41
\l@gujarati=\language42
\l@hindi=\language43
\l@kannada=\language44
\l@malayalam=\language45
\l@marathi=\language46
\l@oriya=\language47
\l@pali=\language48
\l@panjabi=\language49
\l@tamil=\language50
\l@telugu=\language51
\l@indonesian=\language52
\l@interlingua=\language53
\l@irish=\language54
\l@italian=\language55
\l@kurmanji=\language56
\l@classiclatin=\language57
\l@latin=\language58
\l@liturgicallatin=\language59
\l@latvian=\language60
\l@lithuanian=\language61
\l@macedonian=\language62
\l@mongolian=\language63
\l@mongolianlmc=\language64
\l@bokmal=\language65
\l@nynorsk=\language66
\l@occitan=\language67
\l@piedmontese=\language68
\l@polish=\language69
\l@portuguese=\language70
\l@romanian=\language71
\l@romansh=\language72
\l@russian=\language73
\l@sanskrit=\language74
\l@serbian=\language75
\l@serbianc=\language76
\l@slovak=\language77
\l@slovenian=\language78
\l@spanish=\language79
\l@swedish=\language80
\l@thai=\language81
\l@turkish=\language82
\l@turkmen=\language83
\l@ukrainian=\language84
\l@uppersorbian=\language85
\l@welsh=\language86
\babelcatcodetablenum=\catcodetable12
\bbl@pattcodes=\catcodetable13
)
\babel@savecnt=\count193
\U@D=\dimen147
\l@babelnohyphens=\language87

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@attr@locale=\attribute4
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language22) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language22) on input line 108.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
\c@blindtext=\count194
\c@Blindtext=\count195
\c@blind@countparstart=\count196
\blind@countxx=\count197
\blindtext@numBlindtext=\count198
\blind@countyy=\count199
\c@blindlist=\count266
\c@blindlistlevel=\count267
\c@blindlist@level=\count268
\blind@listitem=\count269
\c@blind@listcount=\count270
\c@blind@levelcount=\count271
\blind@mathformula=\count272
\blind@Mathformula=\count273
\c@blind@randomcount=\count274
\c@blind@randommax=\count275
\c@blind@pangramcount=\count276
\c@blind@pangrammax=\count277
) (./temp3.aux)
\openout1 = temp3.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 8.


(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(36.135pt, 542.02501pt, 36.135pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(36.135pt, 722.7pt, 36.135pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=542.02501pt
* \textheight=722.7pt
* \oddsidemargin=-36.135pt
* \evensidemargin=-36.135pt
* \topmargin=-73.135pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 8.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `basictext'.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \showhyphens on input line 8.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg
File: mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg 2013/03/13 v1.0 microtype config. file: Latin Mode
rn Roman (RS)
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./temp3.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 6024 strings out of 481285
 100000,662416 words of node,token memory allocated
 410 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:40,3:2,4:1,5:27,7:83,9:7,11:5
 23152 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 27 fonts using 3522083 bytes
 44i,4n,42p,232b,134s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-italic.ot
f></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular
.otf>
Output written on temp3.pdf (1 page, 7336 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: `Renderer=HarfBuzz` is not a package option but a font option.

Comment: Thanks, latest v2.7i document is misleading, page number Part VI, Section-1, page 54 seems to suggest its a fontspec option "When running a suitable LuaTEX engine with Harfbuzz support, fontspec provides the following options:..." http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

Comment: You should address your observation about the possibly misleading information given in the package's user guide directly to `fontspec`'s maintainer, via the site https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues. TeX.SE isn't the right place to report bugs and other perceived shortcomings of a package.

Comment: @Mico: I know this is not the place to file bugs, but it is a place to share source of misinformation (if one has encountered during debug). That helps entire community.

Comment: Good question, but I’ll vote to close because it was answered in the comments.